# How do you EXPLODE CSV line with a comma in value?

Tags: php, csv, explode

```
"AMZN","Amazon.com, Inc.",211.22,"11/9/2011","4:00pm","-6.77 - -3.11%",4673052
```

**Amazon.com, Inc.** is being treated as 2 values instead of one.

I tried this `$data = explode( ',', $s);`

How do I modify this to avoid the comma in the value issue?

Comment: You may be looking for http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php (However, that's PHP >= 5.3 only)

Comment: @Pekka : In the output when I split the returned values and print each value in a separate line.

Comment: @Galled : Not all values are wrapped in quotes. For instance : 211.22 is not wrapped in quotes.

Comment: @ScottMcGready Please don't just fix one thing in a post when editing. Fix *everything* (grammar, formatting, tags, etc).

Comment: @hichris123 got a small bit of time to kill and don't want to get too bogged down. Figured I'd do a *little* bit of clean up while I was waiting but fair enough

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should probably look into [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) (or [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) if you're loading the CSV from a file)

This will read the CSV contents into an array without the need for exploding etc.

Edit- to expand upon the point made by Pekka, if you're using PHP < 5.3 `str_getcsv()` won't work but there's an interesting approach [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#98088) which reproduces the functionality for lesser versions. And another approach [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#88311) which uses `fgetcsv()` after creating a temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dedicated CSV library. It's been explained over and over that parsing file formats like CSV manually is asking for trouble, because you don't know all the variations of CSV and all the rules to do it right.

Comment: Sorry, bit rusty on PHP, been a while since I worked on it. Peace!